# Show custom view modally on flutter

Tags: view, flutter, dialog, modal-dialog, widget

I'm trying to display a view modally, kind of like an alert dialog, except I need full control over it (which I won't have with a classic alert dialog).

Right now, I can either do this :

```
 onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StationDetail()),
            );
          }));
```

And I have full control over the view (StationDetail), but it's a full screen push, not a modal. And also I'm not sure that is the correct way to do it anyway.

Or I can do this

```
 onTap: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Text("This is a test"),
                  );
                });
```

In that case it's a modal, but `showDialog` does a lot of stuff that I dont want/need. If I give it an alertdialog it looks fine for an alert, but I can't really do anything customization to it.

Here is what my StationWidget looks like :

```
class StationDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So my question is the following :
How do I just show a custom widget, modally, on a view, coming from the OnTap: ?

Comment: You should take a look at [Overlay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html)

Comment: That looks promising ! @Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

You can use PageRouteBuilder:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
              PageRouteBuilder(
                opaque: false,
                pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
                  return StationDetail();
                },
              ),
            );
```

and your StationDetail widget needs to be transparent

```
class StationDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not really it I think. If I do that, I end up with my navigation bar acting like there is a full screen view that appeared (back button appears in the top left on iOS).
Is there a way for the navigation bar to not change at all?

Comment: is navigation bar on StationDetail page? or the page you want to navigate from?

Comment: add this to your AppBar  automaticallyImplyLeading: false